# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Я новичок в JS, интересует такой вопрос
при клика на кнопку button в консоли возникает ошибка 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined
При этом выводится в консоль правльное значение value
Вопрос: почему ошибка в консоли?

HTML

```
<div>
  <input class="myInput" id='radio-1' type="radio" value="1" name="radio">
  <label for="radio-1">Radio-1</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input class="myInput" id='radio-2' type="radio" value="2" name="radio" checked>
  <label for="radio-2">Radio-2</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input class="myInput" id='radio-3' type="radio" value="3" name="radio">
  <label for="radio-3">Radio-3</label>
</div>

<button>Push</button>
```

Javascript

```
document.querySelector('button').onclick = (event) => {

let radio = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');

    for (let i = 0; i <= radio.length; i++) {
  if (radio[i].checked) {
            console.log(radio[i].value)
        }
    }

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p8ntL92y/4/

Comment: `i <= radio.length` -> `i < radio.length`

Answer (score 1):

У вас не правильное условие в цикле используется. В JavaScript массивы нумеруются с 0, т.е. если у вас всего 3 элемента, то это будет от 0 до 2, но условие стоит `i <= radio.length`, т.е. но будет пытаться получить элемент по индексу 3, которого не существует. Нужно использовать `i < radio.length`.